# Ruby Gem Testing Workflow

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

What is the standard for testing while creating ruby gem?

Do most people run something like guard, or write tests and trigger them manually from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby there isn't really a "standard", instead people usually use what works well for them. If you don't like things like guard and prefer to run the tests from the command line, run the tests from the command line.

When I'm coding I run my tests manually from the command-line, but I also have a cron job that will run the tests against the latest commits and email the results every night.

Comment: Good info...Are you doing TDD? Seems like writing tests, running them manually, and then writing code, and manually running the tests could get cumbersome. no?

Comment: When you say it like that it does sound fairly cumbersome ;) in practice I find it isn't.